# Where are the missing books?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

During the "Hitting the books" mission, I had the fight with the caller; the game guide says the books are on her body.  I searched her and the entire room including surrounding rooms but no books anywhere.

Does anyone know where they are or has anyone experienced this problem?

Comment: What game is this? Please tag your question appropriately (or, if the tag for the game does not exist, ask for someone with enough reputation to create it for you)

Comment: -1 for assuming everyone has ESP.

Comment: I tried a Google to see if I could find out what game it was and nothing came up. Anyone else got any idea?

Comment: @IttyBrittyGirlGamer Why bother? As it is now, there is no point in answering this question. Well, or it might be good as an excersise, I guess. :)

Comment: I *think* he is talking about the "Hitting the books" mission in Skyrim, I'll edit accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

If you are talking about Skyrim, the books should be located on the pedestals in around the room. See [Hitting the Books](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Hitting_The_Books). If you still can't find them and you're on a PC, accessing the console and using 'setstage MG03 200' should automatically complete the quest and lead you on to the next one.

Answer (score 1):

The books are sometimes strewn about on the floor during the fight. Look closely on the floor, you will find the missing books somewhere on the floor.