# Who are the most foul-mouthed and sexually deviant characters?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I understand that this is an M-rated game and, as such, it was meant to be played by adults. There are a number of characters that use more "colorful" language than other potential comrades. There are even other characters that are more likely to jump in the sack with ol' Shep than others.

My question is, if I wanted to choose my companions solely based on their chosen verbiage and sexual advances, **which characters should I avoid to avert as much swearing and sexual deviance as possible?**

Once again, I realize there is a dense amount of adult language and content in the game, and said content cannot be avoided completely. I just want to know whom to avoid to minimize the likelihood of these occurrences.

*Edit: Total question rewrite!*

Comment: Sometimes the only winning move is not to play.

Comment: It may be best to not allow young children access to this kind of content in the first place...

Comment: While I agree this game shouldn't be played around children, it *is* a legitimate question for those who want to know which squad members to avoid in dialogue. So, why all the downvotes? That said, I originally thought this was another @GnomeSlice question.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure why I'm getting slammed on downvotes either. It is a legitimate question for those who would rather avoid the more "adult" content. I originally thought I was getting hammered based on the more casual title, so I changed it to what you see now. People still seem to think the question is bad though. I can remove all traces of humor, but I thought humor typically improved question quality. Maybe not. The site -- she's a fickle mistress!

Comment: I think it's a bad question because if the content were minor or easily avoidable, it wouldn't be rated M.  You should expect an M rated game to potentially contain a lot of this, and you shouldn't expect to be able to avoid it and still actually play the game.  Wear headphones.

Comment: Maybe it's how I worded the question, but I obviously realize this game has M-rated content, hence the reason I'm asking about how to minimize this content based on character avoidance.

Comment: @Shinrai There are plenty of M rated games with the option to turn Blood and Gore or Profanity on or off. Unfortunately, this isn't one of them.

Comment: @Tristan - Right, and it's obvious from the question that OP knows that, so that's why I don't think it's a good question.  It's not that I have any particular disagreement with it, simply that it's common sense IMO. (I only chimed in because wow, that is a lot of downvotes, and I think he deserves SOME feedback).

Comment: This is the most downvotes on a non-closed question I've seen yet.

Comment: @Resorath Oh, [there](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/29117/is-it-possible-to-play-fine-high-graphic-card-recommended-game-on-low-graphic) [are](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6918/what-genre-do-games-like-tekken-and-soulcalibur-belong-to) [a few](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/39317/where-are-the-missing-books) [others](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/46680/keyboard-problem-with-skyrim) [out there.](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions?page=325&sort=votes)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To be entirely honest, the character I'd put at the top of the list is Commander Shepard him/herself -  and even when Shepard isn't *being* offensive, the Commander has a tendency to... provoke some of it in those around him. For instance, an Asari bartender just called me an "Anthropocentric bag of dicks." This is... par for the course.

I can't think of a good way to practically censor the single player campaign of the game at all.

If you must play Mass Effect 3 specifically with kids around, stick to multiplayer.

[Just... remember to turn off voice chat.](http://www.penny-arcade.com/comic/2004/03/19/)

Answer (score 4):

The game is rated M. If you don't feel comfortable having young children subjected to any of that, don't have them play the game. There are a number of story cutscenes that are not on the side.